# How to group data in mysql for multiple datas?

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
id | event_id | stat_count | month | year
1  | 1        | 12         | 01    | 2070 
2  | 1        | 11         | 02    | 2070 
3  | 2        | 14         | 01    | 2070 
4  | 2        | 15         | 04    | 2070
```

and so on.

I need to fetch data by grouping by event_id. Month will be from 01 to 12 but not necessarily all months and stat_count might have been inserted in the table. The date provided is not in English date format.
I need to have result as follows

```
event  data
Fevent 12,21,0,3,0,9,0,0,12,23,34,0 
Fevent2 12,0,3,4,3,0,3,2,3,4,0,0
```

and so on.

### Update:

Here is the query I have tried using `group_concat` too:

```
select 
    (select event_name from vital_events where id=VEC.vital_event_id) name,
        group_concat(

                        CASE    when VEC.month='01' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='02' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='03' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='04' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='05' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='06' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='07' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='08' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='09' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='10' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month_nepali='11' then VEC.stat_count
                            when VEC.month='12' then VEC.stat_count
                          else 0 end order  by VEC.month
                        )as data 
        from vital_event_counts as VEC
group by VEC.vital_event_id
```

Comment: How is the 21 for February calculated from the 11 in your sample data?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I don't see a way to get from the source data to the desired data.

Comment: I don't see how that result comes from the table. What is `Fevent`? Where do the `data` values come from?

Comment: And then there's good old: "What have you tried?"

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is probably what you're looking for for the `data` column.

Comment: I have already told that its not english date format and there is event_id so i can get Fevent the event name from another table.

Comment: I have tried using group_concat too. I Will edit the question and post the query i tried

Comment: Can you either add the full table, or show the result as it would be when executed on the part of the table you show?

Comment: Let me be clear. I want to group the data by event_id and show the value from stat_count and show the result which is ordered by month from 01 to 12. I want record for 12 months from stat_count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using a `CROSS JOIN` to find all months that should be included and then using a `LEFT JOIN` against the table with existing values;

```sql
SELECT x.event_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(stat_count,0) ORDER BY x.month) stat_count
FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT event_id, m.month FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT  1 month UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3 UNION ALL  
   SELECT  4       UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6 UNION ALL 
   SELECT  7       UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9 UNION ALL
   SELECT 10       UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) m
  ) x
LEFT JOIN Table1 
  ON table1.month = x.month AND table1.event_id = x.event_id
 AND year = 2070
GROUP BY x.event_id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29de7f/3).

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats what I wanted. It saved my day. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but…

```
SELECT
 event_id,
 CONCAT(
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(stat_count), 0) FROM tbl WHERE id = t.id AND month = 1), ',',
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(stat_count), 0) FROM tbl WHERE id = t.id AND month = 2), ',',
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(stat_count), 0) FROM tbl WHERE id = t.id AND month = 3), ',',
  ⋮
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(stat_count), 0) FROM tbl WHERE id = t.id AND month = 12)
 ) AS data
FROM
 tbl AS t
```

Comment: That won't work because the month will be dynamic too. If data is filled the month will be there, if its not filled I have to assume that the loop goes from 1 to 12 and set value to zero if match not found.